# Want to Restore Android Backup to iPhone

Tags: iphone, backup, restore, android

I backed up my android phone (lg g7) to google, then sold the phone.  I no longer have it in my possession.

I now have a new iphone xr and wish to restore that backup to my iPhone - call history, sms, etc.

How exactly do I do that?

Googling reveals two apps, "Move to IOS" and "TransPhone"... neither of which work in my case.

Comment: Seriously?  Downvotes - what gives?  This is a clear and concise question seeking a specific answer or process.

Comment: I didn’t downvote but was strongly tempted to.  The question “does not show any research effort” is the most applicable downvote reason, though it’s more accurate to say that your action in *selling your phone before you had a working replacement in hand* is really what didn’t show research effort.

Comment: Well, a) the replacement was supposed to have been in my hand the next day and b) moving from my old iphone 6s to android was actually really easy (and I did not have the iphone when I did the data migration then).  The backup exists, so there should be little reason why this should not work. :/  Further, I did google first, came up with the "Move to IOS" app and "TransPhone"... neither of which work in my case. So, the issue is not whether or not I should have sold my phone. The issue is, "This is my situation, how do I fix it?"

Comment: What does "neither of which work" exactly mean, where/how do they fail?

Comment: There is https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201196, but this requires that you have both phones in your hand at the same time.

Comment: @nohillside  I no longer have the android phone.  I do have it backed up to google, though.

Answer (score 2):

All of the transfer methods I am aware of involve having the actual Android phone in hand to do the transfer. Apple has a utility and I think there are third-party utilities as well, but all require you to have the phone itself and not just a backup.

As Android is a product of Google you may find that there are iOS apps that will connect to Google's services and allow you to bring the data over from the Google cloud.

Mail, Calendar and Contacts will directly open a gmail account and suck in the data and, I believe will, Google's photos app for iOS. There are other equivalents but they all depend on those accounts being active and the iPhone connecting to the services to use that data.

However I have never seen a utility that will "restore" an Android backup to an iPhone as the data formats are likely incompatible with the iPhone.

Comment: Well, that is not giving me a lot of hope. Surprised that this process does not exist.

Comment: Contacts, email... that is not an issue.  I don't even care about the call log... just want my text messages back.

Comment: Look for a utility that will *OPEN* an android backup so you can extract those. iOS has a few, one being iExplore